# Переопределение действий по клику мыши

Tags: delphi

Такой вопрос, в Delphi при нажатии правой кнопки мышки открывается popupmenu и одновременно делается действие onClick, а мне это не нужно, мне нужно, чтобы при нажатии правой кнопки мышки выполнялось одно действие, а при левой - другое действие, как это реализовать?

Answer (score 1):

```
procedure TForm1.FormMouseUp(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton;
  Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
begin
  if Button = mbLeft then begin
    //Делай то
  end
  else if Button = mbRight then begin
    //Делай это
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Мне кажется, что это не будет работать с компонентами на форме. Или будет?

Comment: Я уже сделал с помощью еще одного popupmenu и там выбрал отдельный вариант для правой и отдельно для левой мышки. А использовал я этот компонент для Button: нужно, чтобы кнопка делала несколько вариантов.

Answer (score 1):

Давно уже подобного не делал, но вот, кажется, верный вариант.

```
procedure TForm1.ApplicationEvents1Message(var Msg: tagMSG;
  var Handled: Boolean);
begin
  if Msg.message=WM_LBUTTONDOWN then
   begin
     //..........
    ShowMessage('левый клик');
   end;
end;
```

Точно так же есть и другие константы, например `WM_RBUTTONDOWN` - для правого клика.
Утянуто с [форума](http://forum.codenet.ru/threads/41746-Как-отловить-нажатие-кнопок-Shift-или-Ctrl-при-помощи-ApplicationEvents).